# How can I use an eventListener to send a post request using Node and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Before this gets marked as a duplicate, please note that I've found a solution, but it's not working for me.

I'm making a web app that allows a user to log in, do a search for a movie, and then select a movie from the search results to add it to a 'wish list' that's associated with that user. My only background in web development is a Udemy course that I just finished, and this is the first project I've worked on independentaly.

I've got an ejs file that renders the search page. Here's a snippet of that file:

```
<%- include("./partials/header.ejs") %>

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center"> Create new Request for <em><strong><%= currentUser.username %></strong></em> </h1>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
            <input id="search_box" class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Movie Title">
            <button id="search_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</a>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="results" class="row">
    <h3> Results... </h3>

        <div class="card mb-3">
            <div class="row no-gutters">

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <img id="poster_0" class="card-img" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 id="movie-title_0" class="card-title"><strong>Batman Begins</strong> - <em>1984</em></h5>
                        <p class="card-text"><strong>Description</strong>:
                            <span id="movie-description_0">
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <p class="card-text"><strong>IMDB Rating</strong>:
                            <span id="movie-rating_0">
                            </span>
                        </p>
                        <a id="add_button_0" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Requests</a>
                    ........

    </div>
</div>
<script src="/javascripts/apikey.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/search.js" currentUserId=<%= currentUser._id %> currentUserName=<%= currentUser.username %>></script>
<%- include("./partials/footer.ejs") %>
```

In the included script at the bottonm, I create an array of movie objects based on what's returned by TMDB. Here's the code from the script:

```
let baseURL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/';
let configData = null;
let baseImageUrl = null;
let movieData = [];
let currentUserId = document.currentScript.getAttribute("currentUserId");
let currentUserName = document.currentScript.getAttribute("currentUserName");

let getConfig = function() {
    let url = ''.concat(baseURL, 'configuration?api_key=', API_KEY);
    fetch(url)
        .then((result) => {
            return result.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            baseImageUrl = data.images.secure_base_url + data.images.poster_sizes[3];
            configData = data.images;
            console.log('config:', data);
            console.log('config fetched');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            alert(err);
        });
}

let runSearch = function(keyword) {
    let url = ''.concat(baseURL, 'search/movie?api_key=', API_KEY, '&query=', keyword);
    console.log("Keyword is: " + keyword);
    console.log(url);
    fetch(url)
        .then((result) => {
            return result.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                movieData[i] = {
                    movie_id: data.results[i].id,
                    movie_title: data.results[i].title,
                    movie_release_date: data.results[i].release_date,
                    movie_description: data.results[i].overview,
                    movie_rating: data.results[i].vote_average
                };
                document.querySelector("#results").style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.querySelector("#poster_" + i).src = baseImageUrl + data.results[i].poster_path;
                document.querySelector("#movie-title_" + i).innerHTML = "<strong>" + data.results[i].title + "</strong> - <em>" + data.results[i].release_date + "</em>";
                document.querySelector("#movie-description_" + i).textContent = data.results[i].overview;
                document.querySelector("#movie-rating_" + i).textContent = data.results[i].vote_average;
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(movieData));

        });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getConfig);
console.log("The current user is: " + currentUserName + " - Id:" + currentUserId);

document.querySelector("#search_button").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    runSearch(document.querySelector("#search_box").value);
});

=================> MOST RELAVENT BIT BELOW <===============
for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    document.querySelector("#add_button_" + i).addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log("TEST OUTPUT: " + JSON.stringify(movieData[i]));
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var postUrl = "/users/" + currentUserId + "/requests/new";
        xhr.open("POST", postUrl, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(movieData[i])); 
    });
}
```

When the 'add to requests' button is clicked, what *should* happen is that the data in movieData[i] gets converted to a string, and sent as a post request to `/users/id/requests/new`. Here are my route definitions:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const middleware = require("../middleware/auth.js");
const User = require("../models/user.js");


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', (req, res)  => {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/id/requests', (req, res) => {
    res.render('../views/requests', {title: "Profile - Groovie"});
});

router.get('/id/requests/new', (req, res) => {
    res.render('../views/new', {title: "New Request - Groovie"})
})

router.post('/:id/requests/new', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    User.findById(req.params.id, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            user.requested_movies.push({
                movie_id: req.body.movie_id,
                movie_title: req.body.movie_title,
                movie_release_date: req.body.movie_release_date,
                movie_description: req.body.movie_description,
                movie_rating: req.body.movie_rating
            });
            console.log("Added movie " + req.body.movie_title);
            user.save();
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

So here we have our problem: All of the data that's getting pushed to the User object is blank. The `console.log(req.body)` is showing me that there is some kind of error in the way that the post request is getting parsed. Here's what's getting output:

```
{
  `{"movie_id":320288,"movie_title":"Dark Phoenix","movie_release_date":"2019-06-05","movie_description":"The X-Men face their most formidable and powerful foe when one of their own, Jean Grey, starts to spiral out of control. During a rescue mission in outer space, Jean is nearly killed when she's hit by a mysterious cosmic force. Once she returns home, this force not only makes her infinitely more powerful, but far more unstable. The X-Men must now band together to save her soul and battle aliens that want to use Grey's new abilities to rule the galaxy.","movie_rating":6}`: ''
}
```

It took me forever to spot this, but I **think** that what's happening is that, instead of parsing each key-value pair as a key-value pair, the route is parsing the **entire** string as a single key, and the value is `''`

Even if I take out the JSON.stringify bit from within the `XMLHttpRequest.send()` call and manually add a string like `"number_of_dogs: 14, number_of_cats: 3"`, the same weird parsing takes place. The `console.log` from within the route definition prints out `{"<whatever string was passed>" : ''}`

I'm not married to the XmlHttpRequest method for getting the data to the new route, that's just the solution I found here. The course I took only really talked about making post requests via forms. Any guidance would be enormously appreciated.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserurlencodedoptions

Comment: @Sgnl Thanks for the link! I've spent about the last 12 hours pouring over that, is there something specific that you're aware of that I'm missing?